# can't use appendChild on elements, only on body

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to create a function that will add rows and cells to a table with data from inputs, but for some reason after I create a new row and try to use `appendChild` (or just `append`) to put it in the table, the console shows an error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'append')"

Thanks for helping!

```
<html>
 <body>
  <table id="tbl" border="1">
  <table>

  <script>
   function showStudent () {
        let tbl = document.getElementById('tbl')
        let tr = document.createElement('tr')
        document.tbl.append(tr)
      }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `document.tbl`? it is not the variable `tbl` you created! Also you should be using `const` and not `let`.   `const tbl = ...; const tr = .....; tbl.append(tr);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
tbl.append(tr)
```

Instead of

```
document.tbl.append(tr)
```

Comment: thanks! i just started with js a few days ago so i dont really know the difference between const and let but i'll read about it

Comment: Hi! `const` vs `let` won't make a difference in this example.
The problem was that `document.tbl` was undefined.